# Ms word automation table row problem using C#

Tags: c#, .net, ms-word, word-automation

What is the main reason of this error

> No individual rows in this collection can be addressed because the
>   table contains vertically linked cells. '

I have table in which I want to add data (stored in array) but second row of the table is merged and I got this error message.

What can be appropriate solution to remove this error.

Code :

```
if (pCell.Range.Text.Contains("List of components robots"))
{   
    iDT16 = 0; rowcount = 0;
    foreach (int Row in wordDocument.Tables[j].ToString()) // Add row in the table according to data available inside Result array
    {
        while (sDesignation_Componentsrobots[iDT16] != null)
        {
            wordDocument.Tables[j].Rows.Add();
            wordDocument.Tables[j].Rows.SetHeight(28, Word.WdRowHeightRule.wdRowHeightAtLeast);
            rowcount = wordDocument.Tables[j].Rows.Count;
            iDT16++;
        }
    }

    // Fill the row with data and add checkbox in particular table column.
    iDT16 = 0;  iEST16 = 0;

    for (int row = 3; row <= rowcount; row++)
    {
        wTable.AllowAutoFit = true;
        wTable.Rows[row].Range.Font.Bold = 0;
        wTable.Rows[row].Range.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = Word.WdParagraphAlignment.wdAlignParagraphCenter;
        wTable.Rows[row].Range.ParagraphFormat.SpaceBefore = 5;
        wTable.Cell(row, 1).Range.Text = sDesignation_Componentsrobots[iDT16];
        wTable.Cell(row, 3).Range.Text = sEmergency_stopcircuit_T16[iEST16];
        Word.FormField checkBox2 = wTable.Cell(row, 6).Range.FormFields.Add(wTable.Cell(row, 6).Range, Word.WdFieldType.wdFieldFormCheckBox);
        iDT16++; iEST16++;
    }

    break;
}
```

Table with merged row:

[image: Table with merged row]

Comment: The 'location level/pillar' and 'Emergency Stop circuit' cells span rows 1 and 2.  For this reason Word is unable to return a row. It is possible to write code that gets around this issue but in your case I suspect the simplest solution would be to split the text in the two cells and just turn off the border between the two cells so that you no longer have split cells but give the appearance of merged cells.

Comment: can you show me small demo?

Comment: What do you need a demo of?

Comment: Like How to split text and turn off the border.

Comment: These are trivial tasks that can be googled.  In addition, before I spend any of my time, you'd have to convince me that your code compiles cleanly and that you are only receiving runtime errors.  For example, your first foreach loop is utter nonsense as you are converting a table to a string and then expecting to iterate over that string using an int.